# TypeScript what's the right typing for a json that could have a nested field or a flat string in one of the fields?

Tags: typescript

new to TS and I'm running into an issue that I'm ashamed to admit I'm having a harder time figuring out than I had hoped to. I have the following json that I fetch from an endpoin

```
 {
   "status":"ok",
   "upload_id":"someid",
   "url":{
      "url":"https://foo.bar",
      "fields":{
         "ble":"bla",
         "foo":"boo"
      }
   }
}
```

And I'm fetching it like so

```
    fetch(`https://foo.bar/foo`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((result: Record<string, Record<string, string>>) => {
            console.log(result)
            const info: Record<string, string> = result.url;
            const url: string = info.url;
            const upload_id: string = result.upload_id
        })
```

But the problem is that the typing doesn't seem to match up. It's expecting a Record<string, string> but it's getting a string for the upload id. How do I go about letting typescript know that upload_id is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In typescript it is always a good idea, to define the properties as much as possible so that it's easier to write code and detect issues at compile time. So I would say, please don't use `any` or `unknown` as types, because that just really defeats the purpose of using typescript.

##### Solution:

```typscript
interface IFields{
    // if properties are dynamic 
    [key: string]: string;
    // if properties are not dynamic you can using
    foo: string;
    boo: string;
}

interface IURL{
  url: string;
  fields: IFields;
}

interface IResponse{
   status: string;
   upload_id: string;
   url: IURL;
}

// Then use it in the fetch call
fetch(`https://foo.bar/foo`)
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then((result: IResponse) => {
    console.log(result.status);
    console.log(result.url);
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to enforce a check if say 'url' doesn't exist in the response.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite get you. Typescript is a compile time language. It won't really know what the actual value is until runtime. So if you want to put any checks, they will have to be explicit `if` checks ex. `if(result.url) { console.log(result.url) }`

Comment: Ah yeah I guess serializing it would be a next step. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the type as well as the properties that you expect.

when you define `Record<string, string>` you are telling typescript that you expect a generic object who has keys that are strings and values that are strings.

But if you try to access a specific property i.e.

```js
const upload_id: string = result.upload_id
```

Typescript can't guarantee that it's a string as maybe `upload_id` doesn't exist. In order to fix this you have to define the properties that you expect / know will exist.

```js
type UrlResponse = {
  url: {
    url: string
    // etc
  }
}

type Response = {
  status: string,
  upload_id: string,
  url: UrlResponse
}
```

Then when you reference this type in your code you should no longer receieve an error as such:

```js
fetch(`https://foo.bar/foo`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((result: Response) => {
            console.log(result)
            const info: UrlResponse = result.url;
            const url: string = info.url;
            const upload_id: string = result.upload_id
        })
```

Comment: Ahhh I understand this much better now. Thank you.

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat this answer tells you to do exactly what you shouldn't be doing. Please use interfaces in typescript for defining objects.Zecuria please check the when to use types and interfaces [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/types-vs-interfaces-in-typescript/)

Comment: @Salvino for 99% of use cases they are completely interchangeable. My answer remains valid as well as explaining why it's working the way it is.

Typescripts own docs have a section on this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces

Where they say: `For the most part, you can choose based on personal preference, and TypeScript will tell you if it needs something to be the other kind of declaration.` 

Some people prefer one or the other but it really has few consequences.

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat you can use either Interface / Type. As mentioned in my comment above but happy for you to pick whichever answer helped you

Comment: Wish I could pick both since both ended up solving my issue and helped me learn a bit more about TS's behaviour.

Comment: Zecuria, you missed the key point under *Differences Between Type Aliases and Interfaces*. Please read it. It is always ideal to use interfaces for defining objects. As you said there are *few* consequences, that means even you agree that there are consequences. And that's just it. I'm just pointing that there could be consequences and hence proposing an ideal solution. Please use interfaces for defining objects that could grow larger and much more complex in future.

Comment: To go one step further, type can be used for smaller definitions which won't really grow complex in future, ex. `type foo = "hello" | "world"` or `type ID = number | string;`

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but i usually go with `any`, you can also look into using `unknown` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type in place of any

```
// {[key:string]: any}
// example
let data: { [key: string]: any } = {
  p: 1,
  q: "hello",
  c: {
    k: 1,
    m: [1, 2, 3],
  },
};
```

Comment: Ah I can definitely do this but seems like doing any felt like a catch all trick. I suppose I could do with this in the meantime.

Comment: also if you know the response structure, you can add those and put this at the end of interface